# images in div to be in one line

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code, and I am trying to get all the images in one line, however I am only seeing a dot, which I think is the bullet point for the list. What is wrong?

```
  #emoticonscontainer ul li { display: inline; }

<div id="emoticonscontainer">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="smile.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="sad.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="surprise.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="wink.png" /></li>
                        <li><img src="love.png" /></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the image paths are correct? If you move the <img> tag out of the list, will the image show up?

Comment: Is the problem that the images aren't showing up at all, or that they aren't in a single line?

Comment: I tried replacing the img src with an image url in the web and it's still the same

Comment: We're missing something then...Try `display: inline-block` or `foat: left` instead

Comment: is there a way to do this without a ul li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your list type to get rid of the dot:

```
 #emoticonscontainer ul li { display: inline; list-style:none}
```

Your images should be appearing. Perhaps you have the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

Try `float:left` instead of `display:inline`.